# Check empty and numeric input with regex at same time in MVC

Tags: asp.net, regex

First I want to check that if input is null than show error and if input has digit value than also show an error.... So what's pattern for this? I hope that you understand my questions Thanks!

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\D]$", ErrorMessage = "Input Cannot be empty and must have Alphabets only")]

public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is environment you are working in? programming language, web framework?

Comment: Regexps cannot detect `null` values. They only work with strings. You might have meant *empty* string.

Comment: @NRitH I already removed that tag

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah i means that first check input is empty and second check the input has number?

Comment: @Fabio please check i have edit the code for more clear understanding .

Comment: @NRitH check edited code please

Comment: Does it mean you want to display two different messages upon 1) empty string input and 2) if string is non-empty but contains chars other than digits?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah you are right .

Comment: Try adding `[Required]` right above the `[RegularExpression(@"^\D+$", ErrorMessage = "Input can have no digits.")]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i dont want to add [Required] i want to check empty string and digit with Regex pattern at same time .i hope you understand

Answer (score 2):

Your solution does not work for you because the `^[\D]$` pattern matches a string that only contains a single char other than a digit. Note that `[` and `]` can be safely removed as character classes only make sense when they have multiple chars/char ranges in them.

I suggest

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\D+$", ErrorMessage = "Input can have no digits.")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

The `@"^\D+$"` pattern only matches a string that has no digits in it. Note that `RegularExpressionAttribute` patterns should always match the whole input, so `^` and `$` anchors are good to use here.

Comment: `Your pattern does not work` - I think it *works* but in another way: *Match with this pattern*

Comment: @TânNguyễn In answers, "does not work" means "does not work for OP". Edited the wording in answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i understand it and used this pattern that's only wotk for digit checking but not working for empty input. how to check empty string with changing in this pattern?

Comment: @AsifShakir If you need to show error if the input is empty, use `[Required]`. There is no reason for you to want to avoid it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah you are right . But any possible way to check empty string with this pattern ?

Comment: @AsifShakir `^\D+$` requires the string to consist of one or more non-digit chars - it does not match empty input. See [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/v5GNfv/1)

Answer (score 1):

`^\d*$` will match any input value that is either empty or composed solely of digits. Alternatively `\D` will match any input value that has at least one character that is not a digit. For example, in Javascript:

```js
console.log(/^\d*$/.test(''));
console.log(/^\d*$/.test('123'));
console.log(/^\d*$/.test('x1'));
console.log(/\D/.test(''));
console.log(/\D/.test('123'));
console.log(/\D/.test('x1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot be empty")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "{0} must have Alphabets only")]
[Display(Name = "First name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Error message if the input is empty:

> First name cannot be empty

and if the input value contains non alphabet character(s):

> First name must have Alphabets only

---

If you want to *allow* empty value, you could try:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(^$)|(^[a-zA-Z]+$)", ErrorMessage = "{0} must have Alphabets only")]
```

`(^$)` allow an empty string. Then, if it's NOT empty, continue to check with the pattern `(^[a-zA-Z]+$)` (alphabet characters only).

Comment: Without using [Required] how i dont Allow empty string with Regex pattern.

Comment: @AsifShakir In that case, you just need `[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "{0} is not valid.")]`. This is not allowed an empty string and non alphabet characters with the error message: `First name is not valid.`